# Regex to match when not inside single quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I have text like the following:

- `something.somethingelse equals 'a.value'`
- `another.thing.more is 'hello@something.else.again' or this.something is 'abc.def'`
- `substringof('xxxx', profile.firstName) and Profile.Organisation eq 'dd.d@ORG.name'`

I'm looking for a regex that can match the words containing dots, except when they are enclosed in single quotes. In this case it would be:

- `something.somethingelse`
- `another.thing.more` and `this.something`
- `profile.firstName` and `Profile.Organisation`

I've tried messing about with

```
[^']\w+\.+\w+[^']
```

And looking at this [example](http://www.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=89417).

But my regex is so rusty I'm getting nowhere fast.

Comment: What language or tool are you using? Regex details vary across implementations.

Comment: This is in c sharp

Comment: Well, it’s not an **exact** duplicate, but yeah, it seems close enough that the other posting should solve the problem. I came up with this before the question was closed, try it: `((['][^']*['])*( *\w+ +)*)*(\w+[.]\w+)`